# ASP.NET file upload and display on same page .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to asp.net, and I simply need to display a `file upload` control (for uploading a pdf), of which upon the user choosing a file, the same page then displays the pdf right below the file upload control. I've managed to learn quite a lot from setting up the basics myself. But for some reason I cannot get the uploaded pdf to appear in the `object` element I have set on the page. I'm sure I've done a lot of other things wrong in my code, and so please advise on improvements. Refer to the below.

Please forgive the naiveness in this code:

**Razor cshtml file:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PickPdf", "EditPdf", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "fileUploadControl", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" class="chooseFileButton" />

    <input type="submit"
           name="Upload"
           id="Submit"
           value="View PDF"
           class="chooseFileButton"
           onclick="Validation" />
    <br><br>

    <p>@ViewBag.Message</p>

    <object id="pdfObject" name="pdfObject" data=@ViewData["FormFile"] type="application/pdf" width="400" height="200"></object>
}
```

**C# Controller:**

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.CustomView("");
    }    

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PickPdf(){
        var files = Request.Form.Files;

        if(files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            IFormFile selectedFile = files[0];
            return this.CustomView(selectedFile.FileName, selectedFile);
        }

        return this.CustomView("File could not be processed");
    }



    private ActionResult CustomView(string message, IFormFile formFile = null){
        var returnView = View("Index");
        returnView.ViewData["Message"] = message;

        if(formFile != null){
            var readStream = formFile.OpenReadStream();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[readStream.Length];
            readStream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(readStream.Length));
            returnView.ViewData["FormFile"] = bytes;
        }

        return returnView;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of ViewData, have you tried to use a Model?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I do eventually want to go that way. But at the moment I just need upload and present. Im looking into saving the pdf first and then providing a path to the object element, or to web view within the page

Comment: Try convert bytes to base64. If you need, I can post a sample, my friend :d

Comment: @Tomato32 a working example would be great for reference thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the PDF displayed immediately after the user chooses the file, then you need JavaScript for that. Bind an event handler to the `onchange` event of your file input, with something like the following code:

```
$('#MyFileInput').on('change', function () {
    var file = this.files[0];

    if (file.type === 'application/pdf') {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $('MyObjectTag').data = e.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

This uses the JavaScript File API to read in the content of the user-selected file, and then creates a data URL that you can then assign to your object tag's `data`. It's important that you check for the mime-type, so someone can't just load anything into your object tag.

Also, note that this doesn't actually "upload" anything. The user will still need to actually submit the form (or your will need to send the form data via AJAX) to get the actual file to your server. However, this does allow them to preview what they are about to upload without causing a page refresh or actually doing anything irreversible (if it's not the file they actually wanted, they can just choose again). Additionally, because the File API is required, this will only work in modern browsers (IE 10+, and virtually every other browser on the planet).

Comment: where would this.files be coming from?

Comment: `this` is bound to the file input from the onchange handler. The `files` member on that is the collection of user selected files via that input.

Comment: ahh right, apologies. I was trying to access this.files in c# not javascript. I have tried calling the associated controller to pass to it the files, but it returns an empty page, with the correct url in the address bar though. And how do I pass the javascript `file` variable into the c# `url.location=` call?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the method like this. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
private ActionResult CustomView(string message, IFormFile formFile = null)
        {
            var returnView = View("Contact");
            returnView.ViewData["Message"] = message;

            if (formFile != null)
            {
                var readStream = formFile.OpenReadStream();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[readStream.Length];                
                readStream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(readStream.Length));
                var strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                var content = string.Format("data:application/pdf;base64,{0}", strBase64);
                ViewData["FormFile"] = content;
            }

            return returnView;
        }
```